# How does import/export from node_modules works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, import, export

I was wandering if some of you knew how was working bundling (I guess this has something to do with this).

I don't understand why when I do

```
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default'
```

It works (from node_modules) but when I do

```
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from './photoswipe-ui-default'
```

From a copy of this exact same file it does not works with the error

> "export 'default' (imported as 'PhotoSwipeUI_Default') was not found in './photoswip-ui-default'